# truffle develop not working in the pc

Tags: truffle

I am using Windows 10.

** When I run "truffle develop" commend is give me an error:**

```
 λ truffle develop
user@DESKTOP-V44IVRJ MINGW64 ~

$ truffle develop

ExtendableError: Could not find suitable configuration file.

at Function.detect (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\config\dist\index.js:148:1)

at Object.run (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\develop.js:53:1)

at Command.run (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\command.js:136:1)

at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\cli.js:56:1)

at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)

at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:83:1

at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:89:10)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:971:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1011:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:32)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:14)

at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1051:12)

at internal/main/run_main_module.js:16:11

Truffle v5.1.46 (core: 5.1.46)

Node v13.0.1
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What is your OS version and how did you install Truffle?

Comment: The error says you are missing the truffle configuration file. You are in the wrong folder when executing `truffle develop` or the project wasn't initialized properly, ie `truffle init` or `truffle unbox <...>`.

Comment: I am using windows 10.